# How disable activation email and auto activate blog

Tags: registration, wordpress

I have a network of wp blog (one blog per user). 
How I can disable email activation when you create a blog?
I need the blog does not need activation to work

I need to register a new user / blog is **only 1 step**.

I found several ways but were referred to buddypress and I do not have that system. 
I also found a plugin by wpmudev but payment :(

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but create a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and add the following, it should block any email to be sent:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_blog_notification', '__return_false' );
```

To do something else, use it like this:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_blog_notification', 'wpmu_so_25531684', 10, 7 );

function wpmu_so_25531684( $domain, $path, $title, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta )
{
    # Use the parameters to do another action, eg, send an email to the administrator
    // do_something();

    return false;
}
```

To auto-activate, try adding [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90714/12615) (`wpmu_activate_signup` + `wp_set_auth_cookie`) or better yet combining it with the above.

Comment: Create a file called **disable_activation_blog.php** and store it in the wp-content/mu-plugins folder. Inside the file: `<?php add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_blog_notification', '__return_false' );`

Apparently this causes the activation email never arrives, but the blog still needs to be activated to work. It can be otherwise?

Comment: I really need the blog does not need activation to work @brasofilo appreciate your time

Comment: Please, edit your question to add details on what's your goal. I tried to answer this `How I can disable email activation when you create a blog?`

Comment: You're right, I misspoke. Like you said, block the activation email and auto activate blog. I mean in one step. @brasofilo

Comment: I found [this](http://pastebin.com/se5NBVcH#) and apparently works. What I doubt is that if it is legal to use it, I think it is an old version of the [plugin WPMU](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/remove-email-verification-from-signup/) @brasofilo

Comment: Well, it's probably the version that originated the premium plugin, and it has a copyright notice as "free to use". . . . Looks like there is much more to this feature than I thought.

Comment: Okay @brasofilo, thanks for your time and patience! You helped guide me to the correct answer :)